# Что лучше для хранения сообщений в чате, файловая система или MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, файлы

Подскажите пожалуйста что лучше в плане быстродействия файловая система или же база данных?

Для примера возьму чат в котором к примеру будет сидеть ну скажем 100+ человек. Чат работает в связке ajax и php и вот хотелось бы узнать что лучше проверять на наличие новых сообщений файл или же базу данных с учетом нагрузки на сервер

Comment: Ни то, ни другое. Проверять наличие новых сообщений нужно в оперативной памяти, не трогая диск вообще никак

Comment: А можно пример как это делается?

Comment: @andreymal проверка в оперативной памяти никак не противоречит использованию ни БД, ни файлов

Comment: @Ипатьев она ускоряет проверку, не делая лишних запросов ни к диску ни к бд, обращаясь к ним лишь в том случае если новое сообщение было добавлено (да и то для записи), или вошёл новый пользователь.

Comment: @ganz почитайте, как работает файловая система и БД. В большинстве случаев они точно так же будут отдавать из памяти.

Answer (score 0):

База данных является надстройкой над файловой системой. Так что, отвечая на ваш вопрос напрямую - файловая система быстрее. Однако вы не сможете воспользоватся ей непосредственно, вам придется писать код, который будет отвечать за сериализацию, поиск и сохранение данных (этим как раз занимаются базы данных). И вот этот ваш код, скорее всего, будет работать медленнее БД при одинаковых файловых системах. Кроме того, вам придется самостоятельно решать различные проблемы, которые в реализации БД уже решены.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148511/discussion-on-answer-by-darth--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.